# What kind of hash function can give me a 32 bit value from a string?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, hash

I'm using the QT framework so if there is something like this implemented in that, I would use it, but I couldn't find it.

I would like to get random color values for variable length strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you include [`<QHash>`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qhash.html), then you get [overloads of the function `qHash()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qhash.html#qHashx), one of which is:

```
uint qHash(const QString & key)
```